# Infinite Scroll (JS) + iPhone - Images not loading

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, woocommerce, infinite-scroll

So I am using the Infinite Scroll script to prevent the user having to move on to the next page to view more products in Woocommerce. Everything works great except...

On iPhone (and iPad) the images that would technically be on the next page do not load at all once "Load More" initiates... so for example, if I have 1-8 products visible and I scroll down - the rest of the products appear, but only the images for the initial 1-8 products load, but the rest do not.

I have tried implementing bug fixes to no avail... just wondering if anyone else has encountered this and managed to find a fix?

```
<script>
    var elem = document.querySelector('.shop-section');
    var infScroll = new InfiniteScroll( elem, {
      // options
      path: '.woocommerce-pagination a.next',
      append: '.products',
      hideNav: '.woocommerce-pagination',
      history: false,
      status: '.page-load-status',
    });

    // iPhone Bug Fix
    infScroll.on( 'append', function( response, path, items ) {
      for ( var i=0; i < items.length; i++ ) {
        reloadSrcsetImgs( item[i] );
      }
    });

    function reloadSrcsetImgs( item ) {
      var imgs = item.querySelectorAll('img[srcset]');
      for ( var i=0; i < imgs.length; i++ ) {
        var img = imgs[i];
        img.outerHTML = img.outerHTML;
      }
    }

</script>
```

EDIT: I should also add that I noticed an error in the console as follows:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined
    at InfiniteScroll.<anonymous> ((index):970)
    at InfiniteScroll.proto.emitEvent (infinite-scroll.js?ver=1:254)
    at InfiniteScroll.proto.dispatchEvent (infinite-scroll.js?ver=1:688)
    at InfiniteScroll.<anonymous> (infinite-scroll.js?ver=1:1069)
    at InfiniteScroll.proto.appendNextPage (infinite-scroll.js?ver=1:1076)
    at InfiniteScroll.proto.onPageLoad (infinite-scroll.js?ver=1:1052)
    at InfiniteScroll.<anonymous> (infinite-scroll.js?ver=1:1029)
    at XMLHttpRequest.req.onload (infinite-scroll.js?ver=1:1249)
```

Comment: There's a typo in your first loop: `item[i]` should be `items[i]`.

Comment: You got it! Error is gone! Thank you!